# Como utilizar template string em JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, string, interpolação-de-string

Estou com dificuldades para fazer uma função em JavaScript que eu passe uma string e um objeto e ele preencha essa string com os atributos daquele objeto, por exemplo:

```
var user = {
    nome: "danilo", 
    idade: 29
};
var a = "Meu nome é ${nome}, e tenho ${idade} anos";
```

Comment: Este plugin faz justamente o que você está tentando implementar: http://www.jsviews.com

Comment: não queria adicionar mais um plugin no projeto para realizar algo tão simples, mesmo assim muito obrigado.

Comment: Entendo, até pq o JsViews só vai ser realmente útil caso você precise criar um template mais complexo, condições, laços, modelos complexos, etc.

Comment: Relacionada: [Para que serve uma template string (string literal declarada com acento grave "`") no JavaScript?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/97471/para-que-serve-uma-template-string-string-literal-declarada-com-acento-grave/486311#486311)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

JavaScript atualmente implementado nos navegadores não suporta *string interpolation*,. Tem que fazer assim:

```
"Meu nome é " + nome + ", e tenho " + idade + " anos"
```

Ou usar a [função criada pelo Douglas Crockford](http://javascript.crockford.com/remedial.html):

```js
String.prototype.concatenar = (a) => this + a;

String.prototype.supplant = function (o) {
    return this.replace(/\${([^{}]*)}/g,
        function (a, b) {
            var r = o[b];
            return typeof r === 'string' || typeof r === 'number' ? r : a;
        }
    );
};

console.log("Meu nome é ${nome}, e tenho ${idade} anos".supplant({ nome: "danilo", idade : 29 }));
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/String/Supplant.js).

Comment: Resolveu meu problema sem precisar instalar nenhuma lib adicional. Excelente! Fiquei na dúvida só sobre como funciona esse "String.prototype", é uma extensão? Onde leio mais sobre isso?

Comment: O `prototype` está em todo objeto. http://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+prototype

Answer (score 20):

Utilizando as chamadas [Strings de Template](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/template_strings), disponíveis como um dos módulos do **ECMAScript 2015 (ES6)** e que [já está disponível na grande maioria dos navegadores](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#browser_compatibility), você poderia fazer desta forma:

```
var user = {
    nome: "danilo", 
    idade: 29
};
var a = `Meu nome é ${user.nome}, e tenho ${user.idade} anos`;
```

Ou ainda:

```
with(user) {
    a = `Meu nome é ${nome}, e tenho ${idade} anos`;
}
```

Note que as aspas invertidas foram utilizadas para englobar esta string, visto que esta é a sintaxe que deve ser utilizada quando se trabalha com strings de template.

Answer (score 7):

O ES2015 já tem sua própria estrutura de template string, mas enquanto não temos compatibilidade em todos os navegadores, pode usar algo como isso:

```
var data = {
    host: 'twitter.com',
    port: '80',
    user: 'henricavalcante'
};

var a = "http://${host}:${port}/${user}";

var c = a.split('$').map(function(a) {
    if (a.substr(0,1) !== '{') {
        return a;
    }
    var key = a.substring(1,a.indexOf('}'));
    return a.replace('{'+key+'}', data[key]);
}).join('');

console.log(c); // http://twitter.com/henricavalcante
```

Comment: Já poderia jogar o [`.join('')` após o `.map(...)`](https://jsfiddle.net/r7wbb80t/).

Answer (score -2):

Vanilla JS:

```
String.prototype.format = function (args) {
    var text = this
    for(var attr in args){
        text = text.split('${' + attr + '}').join(args[attr]);
    }
    return text
};

json = {'who':'Gendry', 'what':'will sit', 'where':'in the Iron Throne'}
text = 'GOT: ${who} ${what} ${where}';

console.log('context: ',json);
console.log('template: ',text);
console.log('formated: ',text.format(json));
```