# String Format com JavaScript

Tags: javascript, string, formatação

Visando o `String.Format` do C#, que é bem fácil de ser utilizado, busquei algo parecido para ser utilizado em meus códigos JavaScript.

Encontrei algumas implementações um tanto quanto problemáticas, visando isto, gostaria que se alguém possuir um código sucinto e funcional, que o compartilhe com nossa comunidade.

Algo que funcione dessa forma:

```
String.Format("String {0}.", "format");
//Resultado: "String format"
```

Comment: Relacionado: [Template String em JavaScript](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/78750/91)

Comment: Será que só eu fiquei boiando, não entendi o que quer fazer, e olhando as respostas dai sim tive a certeza de que não entendi nada..rsrsrsr

Comment: Como assim @SneepSNinjA rs ..é que no c# tem esse estring format acima que é muitooo prático .. para concatenar texto no meio da string.. ai estava procurando uma implementação parecida. Sacou ? :D

Comment: Mano se acredita que não saquei... seria só concatenar tipo "string" + "outra" ? Acho que não saquei porque não manjo nada de `c#`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Achei algumas implementações no SO. Não sei se alguma atende o que você quer.

Uma delas é o [sprintf.js](https://github.com/alexei/sprintf.js), parece ser uma das implementações mais completas.

[Outra](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4673436/221800):

```
if (!String.prototype.format) {
    String.prototype.format = function() {
        var args = arguments;
        return this.replace(/{(\d+)}/g, function(match, number) { 
            return typeof args[number] != 'undefined'
                ? args[number]
                : match
            ;
        });
    };
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/String/Format.cs).

Uso:

```
"{0} is dead, but {1} is alive! {0} {2}".format("ASP", "ASP.NET")
```

- [Pergunta sobre o assunto no SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2534803/221800).
- [Outra pergunta com outros exemplos](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2534803/221800).
- [Tem essa que eu já respondo aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/78752/101).

Comment: Exatamente isso que precisava.. :) valeu

Comment: Sempre ouvi que não é boa prática extender os objetos nativos do javascript, então fiz uma busca rápida para procurar as razões. Uma delas é que se a String do javascript ganhar uma função `format()` oficial, existe a chance dos seus scripts quebrarem. Eu optaria por fazer uma classe nova, tipo `Str.format("{0} is dead, but {1} is alive! {0} {2}", "ASP", "ASP.NET")` ou algo assim.

De qualquer forma, legal você verificar se `format()` já existe antes de extender.

Comment: Tem o risco mesmo, baixo, mas tem. Aí cada um vê o quanto quer correr o risco e facilitar.

Answer (score 6):

eu utilizo o replace.

```
var teste = "Teste {0}";
teste = teste.replace("{0}", "Sucesso");
```

Comment: +1 para esta resposta por usar Javascript puro. Muitas vezes buscamos soluções mais complicadas do que o necessário.

Answer (score 6):

A partir do ES6 você pode usar esse template:

```
let soMany = 10;
console.log(`This is ${soMany} times easier!`);
// "This is 10 times easier!
```

[Link da resposta detalhada](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610406/javascript-equivalent-to-printf-string-format)

Answer (score 2):

Uso essa implementação:

```
if (!String.prototype.format) 
{
    String.prototype.format = function()
    {
        var args = arguments;

        if (typeof args[0] != "object")
        {
            return this.replace(/{\d+}/g, function(m)
            {
                var index = Number(m.replace(/\D/g, ""));
                return (args[index] ? args[index] : m);
            });
        }
        else 
        {
            var obj = args[0],
                keys = Object.keys(obj);

            return this.replace(/{\w+}/g, function(m)
            {
                var key = m.replace(/{|}/g, "");
                return (obj.hasOwnProperty(key) ? obj[key] : m);
            });
        }
    };
}
```

Usos:

```
"Test {0} Test {1} Test {2} Test {0}".format("str1", "str2")
```

> Test str1 Test str2 Test {2} Test str1 - índice 2 não foi definido

```
"Test {nome} Test {idade} Test {birth}".format({nome: "str1", idade: 15})
```

> Test str1 Test 15 Test {birth} - 'birth' não foi definido

Answer (score 2):

Sei que não responde exatamente a sua questão, mas quando preciso interpolar variáveis com texto em javascript, utilizo o seguinte método:

```
var nome = 'João da Silva', idade = 22, nacionalidade = 'Brasileiro';

var string = [
    'Nome: ', nome, '\n'
    'Idade: ', idade, '\n'
    'Nacionalidade: ', nacionalidade].join("");
```

Esse código retorna:

```
Nome: João da Silva
Idade: 22
Nacionalidade: Brasileiro
```

Pessoalmente, acho que esse código é mais legível do que o código abaixo:

```
var string = 'Nome: ' + nome + '\n' +
    'Idade: ' + idade + '\n' +
    'Nacionalidade: ' + nacionalidade;
```

Além disso, a diferença no desempenho de usar `join` ou `+` não é algo que vá impactar a sua página.

Comment: você pode usar `\n\` para fazer uma multi-line string... [multi-line](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Text_formatting#Multi-line_template_strings)

Comment: Verdade @TobyMosque, dá para escapar a quebra de linha com a barra invertida, mas não é considerado boa prática por causa da facilidade de se errar, já que o javascript interpreta quebra de linha como fim de expressão. Veja essa resposta: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13808106/83284

Answer (score 0):

Eu utilizo este *método* em meu projeto:

```
function format (fmtstr) {
  var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);
  return fmtstr.replace(/\{(\d+)\}/g, function (match, index) {
    return args[index];
  });
}
```