# Para que serve uma template string (string literal declarada com acento grave "`") no JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, string, ecmascript-6

Eu estava mexendo no console do Google Chrome esses dias e daí, como meu teclado estava desconfigurado, acidentalmente digitei o acento grave `` ` `` ao  invés das aspas simples `'` para criar um `string`.

O interessante é que funcionou corretamente:

```
`teste da minha string`
```

Qual é a diferença dessa forma de declarar a string, para essa abaixo?

```
'teste da minha string'
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Os *backticks* delimitam templates ([*template strings*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/template_strings)), nas quais a linguagem é capaz de interpolar variáveis e expressões. Exemplo da MDN:

```
var a = 5;
var b = 10;
console.log(`Fifteen is ${a + b} and\nnot ${2 * a + b}.`);
```

Esses templates podem inclusive conter quebras de linha:

```
var c = `Começa aqui...
         ... e termina aqui`;
```

Answer (score 6):

O acento grave delimita um novo tipo de literal string no JavaScript, chamado *template string* (ou *template literal*). Foi introduzido na especificação ECMAScript 2015 (ES6).

Entre as possibilidades de um *template string*, podem ser mencionadas:

### Quebra de linhas literais

Ao contrário de literais "normais" de string (delimitados por aspas simples `'` ou aspas duplas `"`), *template strings* podem abrigar múltiplas linhas sem qualquer tipo de escape:

```js
const name = 'Foo';
const age = 'Bar';

const htmlStr = 
  `<div>Name: ${name}</div>
   <div>Idade: ${age}</div>`;
```

### Interpolação de valores

É possível interpolar valores dentro de um *template string*. Isso é útil pois evita o uso do operador de concatenação `+`, que muitas vezes acaba "poluindo" o código:

```
const name = 'Foo';
const age = 'Bar';

const oldWay = 'Olá, chamo-me ' + name + ' e tenho ' + age + ' anos.';
const newWay = `Olá, chamo-me ${name} e tenho ${age} anos.`;
```

<sup>Ao interpolar algum valor, ele sempre será convertido ao tipo `string`. Para isso, [`ToString`](https://262.ecma-international.org/11.0/#sec-tostring) será aplicado ao valor interpolado.</sup>

### *Tagged template string*

De certo modo, pode-se utilizar uma template string como "argumento" de uma função. Nesse caso, a função é chamada de `tag` e precede o primeiro caractere de acento agudo:

```
tag`Caracteres da string...`;
```

Uma vez que essa expressão é avaliada, `tag` (que é uma função) é invocada. Ao primeiro argumento passa-se o array de cada string (separadas no local da interpolação). Os demais argumentos (é uma [função variádica](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_function)) são os próprios valores interpolados. As possibilidades disso são infinitas. É a base para bibliotecas como [`styled-components`](https://styled-components.com/). Uma outra aplicação é realizar a filtragem do valor a ser interpolado para, por exemplo, prevenir XSS. [Este artigo](https://wesbos.com/sanitize-html-es6-template-strings) (em inglês) exemplifica.

#### `String.raw`

O `String.raw` permite o uso de strings sem aplicar sequências de escape, como `\n`, `\t` etc. O `String.raw` é uma função *tag* *built-in* na linguagem, de modo que o *tag function* é `raw`, método dentro do objeto global `String`.

[Esta pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/309137/69296) dá mais detalhes sobre o `String.raw`. A [documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/raw) também pode ser útil.

## É realmente um "template"?

Apesar do nome "*template strings*", esse tipo de string literal não se trata, exatamente, de um template propriamente dito, já que, ao contrário deste, os *template strings* não permitem avaliação posterior. Desse modo, todos os valores que serão interpolados devem estar no escopo no momento em que o literal for avaliado pelo *runtime*. Esse tema é mais discutido [nesta outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/475906/69296).