# Pra que serve o String.raw no JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, string, ecmascript-6

Bem, a pergunta é essa mesma.

Gostaria de saber para que serve o método `String.raw` no JavaScript.

Vi alguma coisa na documentação da MDN, mas não entendi muito bem o uso

Tem alguma relação com as [string templates](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/97471/para-que-serve-a-declara%C3%A7%C3%A3o-da-string-com-crase-no-javascript)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

O `String.raw` serve para evitar escapar strings como:

- `\n`
- `\r`
- `\0`
- `\x01`
- `\u000A`

Ou seja se fizer isto:

```js
console.log(`foo\nbar`);
```

Irá mostrar uma quebra de linha, mas se fizer isto:

```js
console.log(String.raw`foo\nbar`);
```

Irá mostrar exatamente `\n`, creio que a principal utilidade disto é enviar via JSON, por requisições (HTTP ou não) sem que ocorra o escape, já que em JSON quem geralmente trata isto é o interpretador no momento da "leitura".

É semelhante ao [`r` usado em Python](https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/strings.html), como por exemplo em Python2:

```
#string escapada
print 'Foo\nbar'
 
#string literal
print r'Boo\nbaz'
```

Será exibido isto:

```
Foo
bar
Boo\nbar
```

Ou como o `@` em C#:

```
//string escapada
Console.WriteLine("Foo\nbar");
 
//string literal
Console.WriteLine(@"Boo\nbaz");
```

---

Respondendo a pergunta especifica:

> Tem alguma relação com as string templates?

Tem relação sim, pois o `String.raw` só funciona com *string templates*, com string, ele não irá funcionar com aspas `"..."` ou aspas simples `'...'`, somente com o acento grave, que em JavaScript é o string template:

```
`....`
```

Como já foi muito bem respondido pelo @bfavareto na pergunta abaixo, isto é uma implementação do ES6:

- [Para que serve a declaração da string com “`” acento grave no javascript?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/97473/3635)

Comment: @dvd o creio ali não tem nada haver com a API e sintaxe, mas sim sobre o transporte de dados, e como disse, creio ser o principal motivo sobre isto e apenas sobre isto, o resto da respostas não e referencias não tem nada sobre, "eu acho", "eu creio", "acredito que",portanto é sobre uma coisa especifica e um ponto especifico da resposta que não muda em nada o resto do enunciado ;)

Comment: Apontamento *grammar nazi*: o nome do acento da crase é *acento* ***grave***. *Crase* é o nome da contração que acontece quando se junta a preposição "a" com outra palavra começada em "a". https://www.normaculta.com.br/palavras-com-acento-grave/ =)

Comment: @nunks como pode ver aonde esta escrito CRASE é um titulo gerado automaticamente a partir da pergunta linkada, logo não fui eu quem escreveu CRASE, foi o autor da outra pergunta ;)

Comment: @nunks editei a pergunta linkada e corrigi o titulo.

Comment: @nunks realmente, li melhor e eu tinha escrito acento crase, obrigado!

Answer (score 7):

O método [`String.raw`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/raw) é uma implementação da 6ª edição do ECMAScript ([ECMA-262](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-string.raw)) e serve para converter [string templates](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/template_strings) (*template literals*) em texto puro.

Segundo a documentação mencionada, ele converte uma string em string literal não-interpretada, ou seja, tudo que estiver dentro da string será considerada em texto puro, ignorando trechos passíveis de interpretação (tags, escapes etc.) porém mantendo a formatação da string exatamente como você escreveu no código (quebra de linhas, espaços, tabulações etc.).

**Exemplo:**

```js
const template = String.raw`Primeira linha
Segunda linha
Tags <b>são ingnoradas</b>
ou qualquer tipo de interpretação,
como este escape -> \n
  <- inclusive este espaço TAB à esquerda
ou este espaço enorme ->        <-
`;
console.log(template);
```

Answer (score 6):

O método `String.raw` é utilizado para obter a string limpa sem escapar os caracteres. Por ex:

```
console.log("String com caracteres \nespeciais");
console.log(String.raw`String com caracteres especiais\n`);
```

Output:

```
String com caracteres
especiais
String com caracteres especiais\n
```

Ele pode ser útil em string templates quando você quer colocar uma expressão regex dentro dela sem escapar o caracter "\".