# É possível fazer Polyfill para Arrow function e Template String?

Tags: javascript

A funcionalidade do [Template String](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/97471/para-que-serve-a-declara%C3%A7%C3%A3o-da-string-com-acento-grave-no-javascript) e [Arrow Function](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/114367/o-que-significa-o-operador/114371#114371) são excelentes para facilitar algumas operações em JavaScript. Porém, parece que nem todos os navegadores ainda suportam a mesma.

Em muitos casos de falta de suporte de funções novas, como `Object.assign`, é possível fazer um Polyfill.

Mas e no caso das Template String e Arrow Function? Seria possível fazer algum [Polyfill](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/194857/o-que-%C3%A9-polyfill)?

Me pergunto isso porque está relacionado com a Sintaxe da Linguagem.

Haveria alguma forma de usar esses dois excelentes recursos em versões de navegadores que ainda não têm suporte?

Comment: Você poderia utilizar o Babel: <https://babeljs.io/setup> Ele vai converter seu código que contenha arrow functions e template strings para um código compatível com navegadores mais antigos. Não acredito que seja possível utilizar um polyfill porque você teria um erro de sintaxe. Já o Babel vai compilar seu código então ele fará as transformações de sintaxe necessárias.

Comment: Quando a questão é interpretador, não há como inserir uma função para tal (caso de shim/polyfill), nesse caso, somente transpiladores.

Comment: @GabrielHeming essa é a dúvida que eu estava. Ouvi comentários que tinha Polyfill para isso em Javascript, porém a pessoa pode ter confundido Polyfill com transpilação.

Comment: A não ser que  existe uma forma de o Javascript fazer o parser do próprio Javascript para transformar num outro Javascript válido :D

Comment: @WallaceMaxters Existe, e é isso que o Babel faz. É até possível fazer em runtime, mas não recomendado por motivos óbvios.

Answer (score 1):

Recomendo que não recorra a `Polyfills` neste caso, utilize o [Babel](https://babeljs.io/), pois ele não é apenas um `transpilador` ES6 (ES2015). O comitê de padrões da ECMA concordou em liberar atualizações anuais para a linguagem JavaScript. O Babel sempre vai utilizar os padrões, ao passo que não sabemos se todos os navegadores o farão, e se eles conseguirão acompanhar as mudança.

Utilizando um `transpilador` como o **Babel**, você não se preocupa com os navegadores, na questão de usar os novos recursos do ECMAscript quando eles são lançados, melhor que esperar que os fabricantes de navegadores integrem os recursos ou usar `polyfills`.