# Como utilizar uma interpolação pré-definida em JavaScript

Tags: javascript, string, ecmascript-6

Estava dando uma lida na [documentação do ES6 que fala sobre interpolação (ou Template strings)](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/template_strings) e vi que eu posso criar "templates escapados", como no exemplo abaixo:

```js
class InvalidParamError extends Error {
  static DEFAULT_MESSAGE = 'Invalid param: ${paramName}.'
  constructor(paramName) {
    super(InvalidParamError.DEFAULT_MESSAGE)
  }
}
```

O problema é que não sei como eu posso utilizar tal template. Até onde eu conheço de interpolação em JavaScript, eu teria apenas duas opções para trabalhar sobre o fato:

- Transformar a propriedade `DEFAULT_MESSAGE` em um método que recebe os campos da mensagem;
- Trabalhar com o `replace` (usando expressões regulares), sobrescrevendo nesse caso o `${paramName}` pelo campo passado.

Existe alguma forma (utilizando interpolação) que eu possa mesclar os campos com a mensagem construída? O que procuro é algo como a interpolação do Python, veja no exemplo abaixo:

```py
DEFAULT_MESSAGE = 'Invalid param: {param_name}'
print(DEFAULT_MESSAGE.format(param_name='foo'))
```

Existe algo semelhante em JS?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

O JavaScript não possui, nativamente, templates. Não confundir [*template strings*](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/template_strings) com um "template real", que pode ser "avaliado" posteriormente — como a função `format` do Python faz.

As *template strings* do JavaScript permitem a interpolação de valores. Pense numa alternativa para a concatenação. Desse modo, você *precisa* ter todos os valores que quer interpolar quando a *template string* for avaliada.

Note também que *template strings* são denotadas com o sinal do acento grave (`` ` ``), e não com aspas simples (`'`) ou  duplas (`"`). É por isso que você não está recebendo um erro no seu exemplo. No seu exemplo, você não usou *template strings*. Usou apenas "strings normais". Veja o erro que receberia se estivesse tentando interpolar um valor que não está disponível no momento da avaliação:

```js
class InvalidParamError extends Error {
  // ❗️ Uncaught ReferenceError: paramName is not defined
  static DEFAULT_MESSAGE = `Invalid param: ${paramName}.`;
  
  constructor(paramName) {
    super(InvalidParamError.DEFAULT_MESSAGE);
  }
}
```

O erro ocorreu porque *template strings* não se trata de um *template* real (geralmente templates permitem avaliação posterior). Como vimos, *template strings*, em JavaScript, nada mais são do que um mero nome diferente para *interpolação* de strings. Sozinhas, as *template strings* não permitem avaliação posterior. Desse modo, você é *obrigado* a fornecer os valores a serem interpolados quando a *template string* for avaliada pelo *runtime* do JavaScript. Caso contrário, um `ReferenceError` será lançado.

No seu exemplo, não ocorreu erro porque a string utilizada (denotada com aspas simples) não avaliara `paramName` (uma referência que, naquele momento, não poderia ser encontrada).

Se você quiser "emular" o comportamento de um template, pode criar uma função para tornar a avaliação da *string* "*lazy*", isto é, preguiçosa. Assim, avaliá-la-emos somente em posse de `paramName`:

```js
class InvalidParamError extends Error {
  static DEFAULT_MESSAGE = (paramName) =>
    `Invalid param: ${paramName}.`;
  
  constructor(paramName) {
    super(InvalidParamError.DEFAULT_MESSAGE(paramName));
  }
}

console.log(new InvalidParamError('Foo').message); // `Invalid param: Foo.`
```

Note que, nesse caso, não faz diferença usar *template strings* (interpolação) ou uma mera concatenação:

```js
class InvalidParamError extends Error {
  static DEFAULT_MESSAGE = (paramName) =>
    'Invalid param: ' + paramName + '.';
  
  constructor(paramName) {
    super(InvalidParamError.DEFAULT_MESSAGE(paramName));
  }
}

console.log(new InvalidParamError('Foo').message); // `Invalid param: Foo.`
```

No entanto, nesse caso, não creio que tornar `DEFAULT_MESSAGE` "*lazy*", transformando-o num método, seja realmente benéfico. O benefício disso, nesse caso, é quase nulo.

Nada lhe impede de avaliar a *string* diretamente no construtor, que é, nesse caso, bem mais simples:

```js
class InvalidParamError extends Error {
  constructor(paramName) {
    super(`Invalid param: ${paramName}.`);
  }
}

console.log(new InvalidParamError('Foo').message); // `Invalid param: Foo.`
```

Em suma, para tornar a avaliação da *template string* (interpolação) *lazy*, o que fizemos foi basicamente criar um método estático (utilizando a notação de *arrow functions*), conforme sugerido na própria pergunta. Uma outra opção, também sugerida, é utilizar expressões regulares para fazer o *replace*.

Enfim, como sempre digo, mais um dos exemplos de como é possível fazer várias coisas na programação. Avalie os custos de cada opção e faça como preferir. :)

Comment: A intenção de criar uma `DEFAULT_MESSAGE` é que eu possa "mockar" e testar mensagens de erros sem depender de ter o erro já construído. podendo então compará-los. Eu uma string com aspas simples como exemplo, e eu já sei que seria possível usar como função, tanto que eu já coloco na questão. Por isso eu perguntei, se havia outra forma de fazê-lo.

Comment: @LeandroLuk, então, na minha opinião, postergar a avaliação da _template string_ (torná-la “lazy”), isto é, transformar em um método, me parece ser o mais ideal. :) Recorrer a uma biblioteca de templates ou até mesmo expressões regulares em casos como esse me parece ser o típico “matar a formiga com bazuca”. :D

Comment: Falando em matar formiga com bazuca, olha o que eu achei: https://www.npmjs.com/package/python-format