# Código não funcionando do jeito esperado para exibir a Soma de Gauss

Tags: javascript

Preciso exibir a Soma de Gauss (100+1=101 , 99+2 =101...). Para isso, fiz o seguinte código:

```js
var contador = 1
var subtracao = 0
var total
var numeroMaximo = 10

// no caso o numeroMaximo é o ultimo número inteiro para fazer a soma de gauss 
// usei o sistema de repetição

for (contador <= numeroMaximo / 2; contador++; subtracao++) {
  console.log(total = contador + (numeroMaximo - subtracao));
}
```

Fazendo um teste de mesa, tenho:

```
// Cada linha é uma iteração do `for`
( 1 <= 5 ; ...) { total = 1 + (10-0) } = 11
( 2 <= 5 ;...) { total = 2 + (10-1) } = 11
...
(5 <= 5 ;...) { total = 5 + (10-4) } = 11
```

Ou seja, daria certo: `1+10 ; 2+9 ; 3+8 ; 4+7 ; 5+6` (como o exercício pede)

O problema é que na execução do código

1. Fica em loop infinito
2. Todo resultado fica = `12`

Estou muito perdido, porque no papel parece dar certo.

Answer (score 2):

Bom, existem alguns problemas no seu código. Mas antes de tudo, recomendo utilizar `;` no fim das linhas, veja [Utilizar ou não ponto e vírgula no fim das linhas em JavaScript?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/3348/100416) para mais detalhes.

### A variável `total` e a exibição com `console.log`

Próximo ponto, você não precisa da variável `total`, porque você apenas quer exibir o resultado no `console.log`. E ainda sobre isso, você está realizando uma atribuição `total = ...` dentro do `console.log`, isso não faz sentido por dois motivos:

1. O `console.log` serve para você exibir uma mensagem de log, por exemplo `console.log('Oi')`. Veja [O que é console.log?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/38057/100416)
2. Se você quer armazenar o valor em `total`, faça-o antes do console. Porém com isso você não conseguirá exibir a Soma de Gauss como deseja:

```js
var total = 1 + 10;
console.log(total); // exibirá 11, não 1 + 10
```

Tendo isso em mente, vamos mexer no código. Por enquanto fica assim (ainda sem funcionar):

```js
// removemos o `var total`
var contador = 1;  // colocamos ;
var subtracao = 0;
var numeroMaximo = 10;

for (contador <= numeroMaximo / 2; contador++; subtracao++) {
  // removemos a atribuição `total =`
  // além disso, tratamos o "+" como texto porque não queremos realizar a operação
  // apenas exibí-la
  console.log(contador + ' + ' + (numeroMaximo - subtracao));
}
```

### O laço de repetição `for`

A sintaxe do [laço `for`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for) é a seguinte:

```
for ([inicialização]; [condição]; [expressão final])
   declaração
```

- `[inicialização]` - Geralmente usada para iniciar o contador de variáveis. Como já inicializamos antes do `for`, não vamos utilizar isso por enquanto (no final da resposta mostro uma alternativa utilizando isso).
- `[condição]` - Uma expressão para ser avaliada antes de cada iteração do laço para decidir se `declaração` será executada ou não. Nesse caso é o `contador <= numeroMaximo / 2;`.
- `[expressão final]` - Uma expressão que será validada no final de cada iteração do laço. Aqui fazemos uso para incrementar (ou decrementar) uma variável de controle do laço. Nesse caso temos duas expressões: `contador++` e `subtracao++`. Para utilizar mais de uma expressão como `[expressão final]`, bata separá-las por `,`.
- `declaração` - É o código que será executado em cada iteração do laço.

Então temos corrigindo, temos:

```js
var contador = 1;
var subtracao = 0;
var numeroMaximo = 10;

// Note que não temos a inicialização e que separamos a expressão final por vírgula
for (; contador <= numeroMaximo / 2; contador++, subtracao++) {
  console.log(contador + ' + ' + (numeroMaximo - subtracao));
}
```

Pronto, agora temos o resultado esperado: a Soma de Gauss.

### Extras

Como eu disse no meio da resposta, vamos fazer uso do inicializador no `for`. Como `contador` e `subtracao` são utilizados apenas no `for`, não precisam ser declarados fora dele. E como vamos utilizar duas expressões, separamos por `,`:

```js
var numeroMaximo = 10;

for (var contador = 1, subtracao = 0; contador <= numeroMaximo / 2; contador++, subtracao++) {
  console.log(contador + ' + ' + (numeroMaximo - subtracao));
}
```

Continua funcionando conforme esperado, mas ainda tem um detalhe. Podemos fazer uso de *[template strings](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/97471/100416)* para exibir o texto, substituindo `contador + ' + ' + (numeroMaximo - subtracao))`, obtendo o mesmo resultado mas de um jeito diferente.

Para isso, basta a string estar entre acentos graves `` ` `` e o que você quer interpretar como expressão iniciando com um sifrão `$` e entre chaves `{}`: `${expressão}`. Veja abaixo como fica:

```js
var numeroMaximo = 10;

for (var contador = 1, subtracao = 0; contador <= numeroMaximo / 2; contador++, subtracao++) {
  console.log(`${contador} + ${numeroMaximo - subtracao}`);
}
```

Usar *template strings* não é melhor nem pior, é apenas outra opção :)

Um último detalhe é que, dentro do `for`, como a `[condição]` é avaliada a cada repetição do laço, significa que sempre estamos fazendo o cálculo `numeroMaximo / 2`. Claro que isso é um cálculo simples e não causará problemas, mas é bom saber disso. Podemos melhorar fazendo da seguinte maneira:

```js
var numeroMaximo = 10;
var limite = numeroMaximo / 2;  // Realizamos o cálculo uma única vez

for (var contador = 1, subtracao = 0; contador <= limite; contador++, subtracao++) {
  console.log(`${contador} + ${numeroMaximo - subtracao}`);
}
```