# API do Twitter retornando "Status is a duplicate"

Tags: javascript, node.js, twitter-api

Eu estou criando um bot no Twitter para responder toda vez que ele for mencionado com um texto aleatório. Está funcionando bem, mas o problema é que a API retorna a mensagem de "Status is a duplicate".

Essa é a parte que escolhe aleatoriamente os textos que estão num array para publicar, mas não acho que o erro esteja nela:

```
var exibir = message[Math.floor((Math.random() * message.length))];
```

E essa é a parte de encontrar, filtrar os tweets e responder:

```
Bot.get("search/tweets", { q: 'hey @namebot' }, (err, data) => {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err.message);
  } else {
    var tweetId = data.statuses[0].id_str;
    var username = data.statuses[0].user.screen_name;
    var tweetsRespondidos = [];
    var i = 1;

    if (tweetsRespondidos.includes(tweetId)) {
      console.log('Esse tweet já foi respondido!');
    } else {
      Bot.post('statuses/update', {
        in_reply_to_status_id: tweetId,
        screen_name: username,
        status: @ ${username} ${exibir}
      }, function(err) {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err.message);
        } else {
          console.log('Resposta enviada! ');
          tweetsRespondidos[i] = tweetId;
          i++;
        }
      })
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: Dê um `console.log` para ver quais status ele está passando e poder entender melhor como está sendo duplicado. Não tá faltando acento grave `\``  no `status: @${username} ${exibir}`?

Comment: arrumei os acentos mas não deu diferença, continua aparecendo. no console log fui ver e os status estão de fato mandando o mesmo único texto várias vezes para o mesmo tweet. quando uma nova menção aparece o bot consegue mandar um texto aleatório como 'oi', e então passa a repetir o 'oi' até que outra menção diferente apareça e ele gere um 'hey', que também volta a se repetir...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Existem alguns problemas no seu código:

1. Não está usando corretamente [*template strings*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/97471/100416) no `status`. A correção da linha fica:

```
Bot.post('statuses/update', {
  in_reply_to_status_id: tweetId,
  screen_name: username,
  status: `@${username} ${exibir}` // Repare nos acentos graves `
}, function(err) {
```

2. Não está adicionando corretamente um elemento no array. O Array possui um método chamado [`push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) para adicionar um elemento nele:

```
tweetsRespondidos.push(tweetId); // Veja que você não precisa mais da variável i
```

3. Se está repetindo o `status`, está repetindo o valor de `username` e de `exibir`. Você não mostra onde está gerando o valor de `exibir`, mas deveria gerá-lo sempre que enviar uma mensagem, ou seja, dentro do `else`:

```
} else {
  // Gere uma nova mensagem antes de enviá-la
  var exibir = message[Math.floor((Math.random() * message.length))];

  Bot.post('statuses/update', { 
    in_reply_to_status_id: tweetId,
    screen_name: username,
    status: `@${username} ${exibir}` // Aplicando a correção 1
  }, function(err) {  
    if (err) {
      console.log(err.message);
    } else {
      console.log('Resposta enviada! ');
      tweetsRespondidos.push(tweetId); // Aplicando a correção 2
    }    
  })
}
```

Deste modo deve funcionar. Note que ainda há chances de você responder o mesmo usuário com a mesma mensagem aleatória. Nesse caso, existem duas alternativas que você pode implementar:

- Enviar um valor único em cada `status`. Pode ser um número que vai incrementando, por exemplo. Pode ser o `tweetId`.
- Armazenar as mensagens enviadas para cada usuário. Desse modo, você consegue validar se aquele usuário já recebeu aquela mensagem antes de enviá-la novamente.

A segunda alternativa não necessariamente é a melhor. Pode acontecer do usuário "gastar" todas as mensagens do seu bot. O Twitter tem um tempo que permite o `status` repetir, se não me engano, mas não sei confirmar isso.

Se quiser resolver esse problema, acredito que a primeira opção seja válida. Se você tem muitas mensagens aleatórias e poucas chamadas do mesmo usuário num curto espaço de tempo, talvez nem precise se preocupar com isso.

Comment: obrigada, foi problema no exibir mesmo que estava fora do else, muito obrigada mesmo!