# Como colocar aspas numa string javascript

Tags: javascript

Tenho este codigo:

```
colors = ["red","green"]
let xmlRowString = "<imagens>";
for(let y = 0; y < this.colors.length; y++){
  let r = colors[y];
  xmlRowString += "<imagem class="+r+"></imagem>";
}
xmlRowString += "</imagens>";
```

Isto retorna:

```
<imagens><imagem class=red></imagem> <imagem class=green></imagem></imagens>
```

O que preciso:

```
<imagens><imagem class="red"></imagem><imagem class="green"></imagem></imagens>
```

É sobre o local storage.

Comment: Qual a relação do problema com *local storage*?

Comment: Quando faço let parser = new DOMParser(); xmlDoc=parser.parseFromString(localStorageRow,"text/xml"); nao reconhece a string

Answer (score 6):

O mais fácil é você utilizar *template strings*:

```
xmlRowString += `<imagem class="${r}"></imagem>`;
```

- [Template String em JavaScript](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/78750/5878)
- [Template strings no MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/template_strings)

O fato de usar o acento grave permite que você utilize aspas dentro da string e, principalmente, permite fazer a interpolação com variáveis.

Outra forma seria escapar devidamente as aspas ou utilizar aspas simples.

```
// Escapando as aspas
xmlRowString += "<imagem class=\""+r"\"></imagem>";

// Usando aspas simples
xmlRowString += '<imagem class="'+r+'"></imagem>';
```

Comment: da tudo erro...

Comment: @Yunrin127 mas é o que responde a sua pergunta. Dizer que dá erro não ajuda em nada, precisamos de informações. O que fez, como fez, porquê fez, qual a mensagem de erro, como executou, etc. Porém, isso provavelmente deverá ser outra pergunta, pois nessa você perguntou apenas como adicionar as aspas - e isso foi feito.

Answer (score 3):

Basta colocar \" (Barra e aspas) dentro das aspas para que ela seja identificada como caractere.

```
 colors = ["\"red\"","\"green\""];
```