# JavaScript Console.log (iniciante)

Tags: javascript, node.js

Ola, comecei ontem a estudar Js, num dos desafios da RockSeat sobre Js é dar console.log() e dar como resultado: "Rua dos Pinheiros" .Mas por se tratar de uma string q puxo de uma variavel sai apenas : Rua dos Pinheiros , sem aspas, como deixar aspas?
[link para a explicacao do desafio](https://skylab.rocketseat.com.br/api/files/1566498717618.pdf)

Comment: Isto responde à sua pergunta? [Como colocar aspas numa string javascript](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/354245/como-colocar-aspas-numa-string-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

Uma maneira de resolver é colocar as aspas envolvendo a string que gostaria de imprimir.

```
const endereço = 'Rua dos Pinheiros'
console.log(`Eu moro na "${endereço}"`);
```

Comment: eu usei  rua: ' "Rua dos pinheiros" ', e funciono aqui, mesmo assim obg