# Inserir variável em uma expressão regular

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

Preciso alterar o nome dos inputs após estes serem clonados. Por exemplo: `order-recipient-name[0]` ficaria `order-recipient-name[1]` e daí por diante.

O que eu tentei:

```
var current_counter = block.data('count');
var new_counter = current_counter + 1;

block.html(function(i, block) {
    return block.replace(/\[0\]/g, '['+new_counter+']');
});
```

Agora preciso informar a variável no lugar do `0`. Mas quando mudo para:

```
return block.replace(`/\[${current_counter}\]/g`, '['+new_counter+']');
```

Não funciona. O eslint retorna um erro:

> Unnecessary escape character: \[ no-useless-escape

Comment: Mas porque você quer substituir `"[N]"` por `"[N]"`... Não seria substituir `"[0]"` por `"[N]"`?

Comment: @fernandosavio fiz a correção no código.

Comment: Pq não seta o nome do input com `$(seletor).attr('name', 'order-recipient-name['+new_counter+']')`? Acho que seria mais simples.

Comment: @Sam porque são vários inputs com padrões de nomes diferentes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basicamente, dentro de uma [*template string*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/78768/112052), o caractere `\` [deve ser escapado](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31093356), sendo escrito como `\\`. Veja a diferença:

```js
let current_counter = 1;
console.log(`/\[${current_counter}\]/g`); // imprime "/[1]/g"
console.log(`/\\[${current_counter}\\]/g`); // imprime "/\[1\]/g"
```

Mas só isso não é suficiente. `/[1]/g` é a [forma literal de uma expressão regular](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#Creating_a_regular_expression): as barras no início e fim são delimitadores e não fazem parte da regex em si, e o `g` é uma das muitas [*flags*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#Parameters) que podem ser usadas para alterar o comportamento da mesma (no caso, em um `replace` ela serve para substituir todas as ocorrências, então no seu caso ela não parece ser realmente necessária, já que você só quer substituir uma ocorrência).

Só que no seu caso, você precisa montar dinamicamente uma string que corresponde a uma expressão, então a forma de fazer isso é passando a string para o construtor de [`RegExp`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp). A diferença é que neste caso a string não deve ter as barras no início e fim, e a *flag* `g` é passada separadamente, no segundo parâmetro:

```js
let current_counter = 1;
let regex = new RegExp(`\\[${current_counter}\\]`, 'g');
let novo_valor = 'teste[1]'.replace(regex, `[${current_counter + 1}]`);
console.log(novo_valor); // teste[2]
```

Comment: Como sempre, boa resposta. Eu só não entendi porque o AP está usando Regex, podendo passar uma string e evitar de compilar uma regex desnecessariamente...

Comment: @fernandosavio Pois é, eu gostei da sua solução de ter um `input` modelo, mas *talvez* no caso do AP ele nem sempre tenha o `[0]` disponível, sei lá... Sem mais contexto, é difícil saber...

Comment: Exato, formulei minha resposta sem saber o que é `block`. Só que existe um detalhe, se ele estiver usando PHP basta apenas que todos tenham `name="order-recipient-name[]"`.. e pronto, não precisa de frescura no JS

Comment: Enfim, sem mais informações só me resta deixar estes comentários na resposta escolhida para ajudar alguém no futuro..

Answer (score 1):

Supondo que `block` seja uma string, o método [`String.prototype.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) recebe como primeiro parâmetro uma regex OU uma string.

Se o primeiro parâmetro for uma string, é feita a substituição da primeira ocorrência da substring recebida.

Então você não precisa inserir uma variável na Regex, basta você concatenar uma string com o número:

```
let new_counter = 9
"order-recipient-name[0]".replace("[0]", `[${new_counter}]`)
// "order-recipient-name[9]"
```

#### Exemplo

```js
let input_modelo = document.getElementById('modelo');
let container = input_modelo.parentElement;
let button = document.getElementById('add-new');

function clone_input() {
    let new_input = input_modelo.cloneNode();
    new_input.id = null;  // `id` deve ser único
    
    // Atualiza o `name` do input com o contador de elementos
    let count = container.querySelectorAll('.super-input').length;
    new_input.name = new_input.name.replace('[0]', `[${count}]`);
    
    // Apenas para mostrar qual é o `name` do input
    new_input.value = new_input.name;
    
    container.appendChild(new_input);
}

button.addEventListener('click', clone_input);
```

```css
input.super-input {
    display: block;
    margin: 0.5rem;
}
```

```html
<button id="add-new">Add</button>
<fieldset>
  <input id="modelo" name="order-recipient-name[0]" class="super-input" value="order-recipient-name[0]">
</fieldset>
```