# pegar o valor da variável em javascript

Tags: javascript

Escrevo a minha tabela desta forma:

```
for (var i = pagina * tamanhoPagina; i < data.length && i < (pagina + 1) *  tamanhoPagina; i++) {
    Ida = data[i][0];
    Paraa = data[i][9];;
    tbody.append(
          $('<tr class="table__row">')
                .append($('<td class="table__content" data-heading="De" ${ Status } != "0"?" style="font-weight:bold; font-size: 90%" ":" style="font-weight:normal; font-size: 90%"">').append(data[i][1]))
                .append($('<td class="table__content" data-heading="Tipo" ${ Status } != "0"?" style="font-weight:bold; font-size: 90%" ":" style="font-weight:normal; font-size: 90%"">').append(data[i][8]))
                .append($('<td class="td-info apagar table__content" data-heading="Assunto" data-alerta="${ Ida }, ${ Paraa }"  ${ Status } != "0"?" style="font-weight:bold; font-size: 90%" ":" style="font-weight:normal; font-size: 90%" ">').append(data[i][2]))
                .append($('<td class="table__content" data-heading="Conteúdo" ${ Status } != "0"?" style="font-weight:bold; font-size: 90%" ":" style="font-weight:normal; font-size: 90%"">').append(data[i][3]))
                .append($('<td class="table__content" data-heading="Estado" ${ Status } != "0"?" style="font-weight:bold; font-size: 90%" ":" style="font-weight:normal; font-size: 90%"">').append(data[i][4]))
                .append($('<td class="table__content" data-heading="Recebido" ${ Status } != "0"?" style="font-weight:bold; font-size: 90%" ":" style="font-weight:normal; font-size: 90%"">').append(data[i][5]))
        )
```

Nesta linha:

```
.append($('<td class="td-info apagar table__content" data-heading="Assunto" data-alerta="${ Ida }, ${ Paraa }"  ${ Status } != "0"?" style="font-weight:bold; font-size: 90%" ":" style="font-weight:normal; font-size: 90%" ">').append(data[i][2]))
```

Pretendo pegar na variável `Ida` e `Paraa` para remover a linha na base de dados. Se fizer `console.log(Ida); console.log(Paraa);` antes do `tbody.append(` as variáveis têm o valor correto, mas na linha não envia os valores das variáveis apenas o nome.

Dentro da linha tenho desta forma:  `data-alerta="${ Ida }, ${ Paraa }"` mas desta forma as variáveis não recebem os valores.

O `js` para eliminar a linha na base de dados é este:

```
function deletar(){
    var ids = []; //arraypara armazenar os id's a serem deletados
    $(".colorir").each(function(){ //percorre todos os tr que possui a classe colorir
        ids.push($(this).find(".apagar").attr("data-alerta")); //adiciona o id da linha ao array
        $(this).remove();
    })
    console.log(ids);
    $.ajax({
        url: './delalerta',
        type: 'POST',
        cache: false,
        data: {ids:ids},
        error: function(){

        },
        success: function(result)
        { 
        }
    });
    //szer a chamada para remo褯 das linhas no php
  
}
```

Comment: Para usar a sintaxe `${variável}`, a string deve estar delimitada por `\`` em vez de aspas. Ex: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/78768/112052

Comment: @hkotsubo se colocar data-alerta=`${ Ida }, ${ Paraa }`envia as variáveis vazias

Comment: Eu quis dizer: `append($(\`<td class=etc data-alerta="${ Ida } etc\`))`. Toda a string delimitada por `\`` em vez das aspas - agora não vou conseguir testar, mas pra usar essa sintaxe tem que ser assim, com `\``

Comment: @hkotsubo é mesmo isso. Funcionou

Comment: @Bruno como chamas essa função `deletar`? podes mostrar esse event handler que escuta o clique?